# showing a SPAN that contain description text inside a jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application. and i am using a web template which can be accessed from the following [link](http://static.livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_47767/index-2.html).

now the web template is great but it suffer from the following usability problem :-

- if you hover over an image (any of the villas images for example) a description text and a search icon will be shown, which is fine.
- but when you click on an image it will be shown inside a jQuery slider. but when the image is displayed inside the jquery slider no description text will be shown (even if you hover over the image). and this is the problem i am trying to fix.

so i tried finding a way to show the same description text inside the slider but i failed. one approach which partially worked , is that i modified the `touchtouch.jquery.js` script by adding the following timer to the `showImage` function:-

```
function showImage(index){

            // If the index is outside the bonds of the array
            if(index < 0 || index >= items.length){
                return false;
            }

            // Call the load function with the href attribute of the item
            loadImage(items.eq(index).attr('href'), function(){
                placeholders.eq(index).html(this);
// START. this is my custom code
                var allcaptions = $(".list_carousel2 span");

                // setTimeout is a hack here, since the ".placeholders" don't exist yet
             setTimeout(
                function t() {

                    $(".placeholder").each(function (i) {
                        // in each .placeholder, copy its caption's mark-up into it (remove the img first)
                        var caption = allcaptions.eq(i).clone();
                        caption.find("img").remove();
                        $(this).append("<div class='thumb'>" + caption.html() + "</div>");
                    });
                    }
                    , 1000);
          //end of my custom code          
            });
        }
```

the result for the following markup :-

```
 <div class="pagination2" id="pagin2"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="list_carousel2 responsive">
                        <ul id="carousel2">
                            <li>
                                <figure><a href="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_47767/img/page3_bigimg1.jpg" class="thumb"><img src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_47767/img/page3_img1.jpg" alt=""><span><strong>Project name:</strong><em>villa2</em></span></a></figure>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <figure><a href="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_47767/img/page3_bigimg2.jpg" class="thumb"><img src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_47767/img/page3_img2.jpg" alt=""><span><strong>Project name:</strong><em>Villa</em></span></a></figure>
                            </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div></div>
```

when i hover over the image on the web page (not on the slider) every thing will be fins as follow:-

[image]

but when i click on the image and the jquery slider opens , the text will be shown as follow:-

[image]

so can anyone advice on the following:-

1. how i can modify the slider to show the text inside a box and on the left side of the image , similar to how it is rendered inside the web page when you hover over the image ?
2. Currently if i click on the next and previous arrows inside the jquery slider, the rendered images will be shown on the bottom of the page for around 1 second then it will re-position on the middle,, not sure if this is related to the timer the defined inside the touch scrip ? becuase before adding the custom timer i did not face this problem ...

i tried to create a project for my current system on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dx8qdoph/5/ but not sure why the slider will not be shown..

Comment: why not use fancybox?

Comment: @Pekka can you adivce more on this please ?

Comment: please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/2LXNh/ i am guessing your needs is something the same in a way?

Comment: @Pekka thanks a lot for the reply.. But actually i was searching for a solution that utilize my current scripts mainly touchTouch.jquery.js ,, but seems you are suggesting to use a new script named fancybox.js and i am afraid this will require a huge modifications to be done in my case ...or fancybox and work with touch.js ?